# SonarQube 5.1 fails execution with message "The project already being analyzed"

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

We have had occurrences where a SonarQube job is running for hours, appears to be hung with no ETA on its completion in our CI environment. We have used a workaround solution of not only aborting the build job, but there seems to be a secondary process executing SonarQube on the CI agent itself. I have read that specifying sonar.forceAnalysis=true should resolve the issue but this has been deprecated as of version 3.X and there is no need to use this analysis parameter. We would like to be able to proactively address this and not have to respond after a team running SonarQube notifies us of this issue. Is there some way of specifying a timeout where the process running the analysis will just terminate?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for killing the analysis running in your CI environment after a certain time, I would suggest you look into the feature offered by your CI environment.

There is no such thing in SonarQube.

As a side note, you should have a look into the upcoming 5.2 release of SonarQube. We have cut the connection to the database from the analyzer which means the error “The project already being analyzed” can not occur any more. In addition, quite a bunch of work done by the analysis job has been moved to the server which allow it to run faster.